# DefaultButton in MultiView.ActiveViewChanged Event

Tags: c#, asp.net, multiview, multiviews

I am using a `multiview` control in asp.net, and on `ActiveViewChanged`  event I want set default button programmatically as of the selected view so am using code:

```
if(myMultiview.GetActiveview() == myView)
   this.Page.Form.DefaultButton = btnDefault.UniqueID;
```

here `btnDefault` is exist in `myView`, even though it throws exception `'System.NullReferenceException'`

please suggest me the solutions

Comment: What line of code do you get 'System.NullReferenceException' ? Probably, **btnDefault** is not put in **myView**

Comment: I got exception on 
`this.Page.Form.DefaultButton = btnDefault.UniqueID;` and `btnDefault` is putted in the `myView`

Answer (score 0):

I had similar type of problem, And i try this,

> ```
>     <asp:Panel id="myPanel" runat="server" DefaultButton="ButtonID">
>     <asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server"  ActiveViewIndex="0">
>         <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server" >
>             <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
>         </asp:View>
>         <asp:View ID="View2" runat="server">
>             <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button2_Click" />
>         </asp:View>
>     </asp:MultiView>
>     </asp:Panel>
>
> </div>
> </form>
> ```

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myPanel.DefaultButton = "Button1";
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("View1 Button is clicked");
        MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 1;
        myPanel.DefaultButton = "Button2";
    }
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("View2 Button is clicked");
        MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 0;
    }
```

may be help you.

Comment: Im getting `this.form1` or `this.form` or `this.Page.form` as `null` at runtime